# How should I evaluate this indefinite integral involving natural logarithm?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find $\int \ln(5x^3)dx$.

Based on my Ti-89 graphing calculator, the answer I found is $x\cdot \ln(x^3)+(\ln(5)-3)\cdot x$. But I want to know how to get to this answer. I know that by the general formula/rule, $\int \ln(x)dx=\frac{1}{x}+c$ but how to apply that to this problem?

Comment: Hint: Use log properties.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. $\int \ln{x}dx = x\ln{x} - x$

Comment: The OP probably mistyped $\int(1/x) dx=\ln(x)+C$. The OP could use integration by parts, with the Chain Rule to differentiate $\ln(5x^3)$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Based on OP's other questions involving ODEs, it's quite surprising to see him asking this integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining what others have noted, this would be the full solution to your integral:

From the property $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$, we rewrite the integrand $\ln(5x^3)=\ln5+\ln x^3$, so:
$$\int \ln(5x^3)dx=\int \ln5+\ln x^3dx=\int \ln5dx+\int\ln x^3dx=x\ln5+\int \ln x^3dx$$
From the property $\ln a^b=b\ln a$, we rewrite $\ln x^3=3\ln x$, therefore:
$$x\ln5+3\int1\cdot \ln xdx$$
We can find the integral of $\ln x$ using integration by parts (your formula is almost correct, except it works the other way around, since it applies to the **derivative** of $\ln x$, **not its integral**):
$$u=\color{#C00000}{\ln x} \quad du=\color{#008080}{\frac{1}{x}}dx$$
$$dv=1 dx \quad v=\color{#C00000}{x}$$
$$\int\ln xdx=\color{#C00000}{x\ln x}-\int \color{#C00000}{x}\cdot\ \color{#008080}{\frac{1}{x}} dx=x\ln x-x+c_1$$
Using our previous results, we find the initial integral:
$$x\ln5+3x\ln x-3x+c$$
We can again use the property $b\ln a=\ln a^b$ to rewrite $3\ln x=\ln x^3$. Thus, the final answer:
$$\int \ln(5x^3)dx=x\ln x^3+x\ln5-3x+c$$
Which is exactly what you found using a calculator, if you factor out $x$ for the terms $x\ln5$ and $3x$.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Now I know it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 15):

Remember these two rules: $$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)\text{ and }\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$$So the integral really is $$\int(\ln5+3\ln x)dx$$Can you continue from here?

Edit: Use that $\int\ln xdx=x(\ln x-1)+C$, what you thought was the integral is actually its derivative with a $+C$ mixed in.

Comment: Thinking that the antiderivative of $\ln x$ is the derivative, probably not.

Comment: You were right. What was I thinking earlier?

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Thank you all for the ten upvotes, I expected this in my other more advanced answers lol.

Comment: I think the reason for a lot of upvotes is that the answer is easy to understand for pretty much all of the 600-or-so people who saw this. The same sort of thing happened to me a few times in the past. I would get fewer upvotes--or none at all--on my answers about stuff as advanced as, say, a hypergeometric power series. Anyways, +1 for the answer **:)**

Answer (score 7):

Your statement
$$\int \ln x \, dx = \frac{1}{x} + C$$
is incorrect.  You've mixed up integration and differentiation.  The correct formula is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigl[ \ln x \bigr] = \frac{1}{x},$$
and
$$\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln |x| + C.$$

Instead, you would use integration by parts with the choice $$u = \ln x, \quad du = \frac{1}{x} \, dx, \\ dv = dx, \quad v = x,$$ to obtain
$$\int \ln x \, dx = uv - \int v \, du = x \ln x - \int x \cdot \frac{1}{x} \, dx = x \ln x - \int 1 \, dx = x \ln x - x + C.$$

Comment: Thank you for the help.